# Object Manager argument replacement using nested array in custom module of Magento2

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, di, object-manager

Alan has written a great tutorial [object manager argument replacement](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement) through `di.xml` . Everything works fine for me except nested arrays:

```
<type name="Pulsestorm\TutorialObjectManagerArguments\Model\Example">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="thearray" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="baz" xsi:type="string">
          <item name="0" xsi:type="string">one</item>
          <item name="1" xsi:type="string">two</item>
          </item>
        </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
```

After using above `di.xml` configuration and running `php bin/magento ps:tutorial-object-manager-arguments` it says

> There are no commands defined in the "ps" namespace

I'm missing something or the process of nesting arrays is changed now ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this error related to bin/magento utility. It tries to find command "tutorial-object-manager-arguments" in "ps".
It is possible, that you have not installed a module or something went wrong with the module.

UPD. baz cannot be a string, it should be an array

```
<type name="Pulsestorm\TutorialObjectManagerArguments\Model\Example">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="thearray" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="baz" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="0" xsi:type="string">one</item>
          <item name="1" xsi:type="string">two</item>
          </item>
        </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: This module is installed and working except my above configuration. After making baz to an array type, it shows other values but with error `[ErrorException]  Array to string conversion `

Comment: maybe cause the code waits, that $thearray  should contain elements that can be converted to a string. look at [Command class](https://github.com/astorm/magento2-tutorial-objectmanager-arguments/blob/master/app/code/Pulsestorm/TutorialObjectManagerArguments/Command/Testbed.php#L94)